# Issue with using multiple Iif lines in a Font changing expression in Microsoft Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 to produce a table that uses a query (connected to a local sql server) as the data source.  I am trying to use conditional formatting on the font color.

This works:

```
=Iif(Fields!Status_RC.Value = "Open", "DarkBlue",
Iif(Fields!Status_RC.Value = "Work In Progress", "SeaGreen","Red"))
```

But this does not:

```
=Iif(Fields!Status_RC.Value = "Open", "DarkBlue",
Iif(Fields!Status_RC.Value = "Past Due", "Red",
Iif(Fields!Status_RC.Value = "Work In Progress", "SeaGreen","Red"))
```

And I do not understand why.
Thanks in advance for your assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`=Iif(Fields!Status_RC.Value = "Open", "DarkBlue",
Iif(Fields!Status_RC.Value = "Past Due", "Red",
Iif(Fields!Status_RC.Value = "Work In Progress", "SeaGreen","Red")))`